# Designing AWS logging solution

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for a forensic logging solution for 120 applications on EC2. The solution must perform real-time, support replay it messages, must persist the logs. 
Which services I should be using for this purpose as the services look very similar to me. Athena, Kinesis, SQS, Elastic Search, EMR?

Comment: Since you mentioned forensic logging, do you plan to log the forensic data to a service or does it include the forensic information of the changes happened to the AWS environment itself including EC2 instances?

Comment: What is the volume of events logged per minute?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of products which can help you with this, such as datadog, stackdriver, etc. If you want to stay within the AWS ecosystem, look at Cloudwatch Logs.